# how to recreate missing socket of running supervisord process

Tags: linux, sockets, unix, supervisord, unix-socket

It happens to me pretty often on different boxes that supervisord socket file disappears for some reason. Haven't investigated if this is because of bug or different reason, but I wonder if it's possible to recreate / reconnect to this socket handled by supervisord. Process is still running and I can see this

```
> lsof -c supervisord
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE  SIZE/OFF       NODE NAME
[...]
superviso 16886 root    3w   REG                9,1     85344    2753325 /var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log
superviso 16886 root    4u  unix 0xffff880059691800       0t0 3662006852 /var/tmp/supervisor.sock.16883
superviso 16886 root    5u  unix 0xffff88017c6f7c00       0t0 3661998412 socket
[...]
```

But /var/tmp/supervisor.sock.16883 file doesn't exist. Is there any way to recreate socket file handled by this supervisord process? I know I can restart supervisor but I'd like to avoid it

Comment: You're kidding, right? You can't be bothered to investigate your bugs but you're asking whether there is some workaround for your unknown bug?

Comment: it's not my bug, but rather sth in supervisord or system itself. Anyway, general question is whether it is possible to create somehow missing socket file and connect it to socket opened by process (as on lsof output)

Comment: I found I can send HUP signal to supervisord process and then socket is recreated without restarting process, but unfortunately all children processes are restarted. So it's still not satisfactory answer for me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug (or a malfunction from supervisord. Take a look [here (Serverfault)](https://serverfault.com/questions/808732/supervisor-sock-file-missing) and [here (github)](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/480)

Comment: I really want to get info if connection to supervisord using socket can be recreated. Thanks anyway for your input :)